# Filtering a result by the content of another table

Tags: database, powerbi, dax, data-modeling, powerbi-desktop

I'm supposed to do a **stakked column chart visualization about the total number of permits granted by authorizing department.** So far ok, the problem is my datamodel.

My datamodel consists in 3 main tables:

1. PDT's(work permits)
2. Departamentos (SubDepartments)
3. Referencia(Departments)

I leave here the type of relationship between them:

[image: The relationship of my tables]

The 1st table below It's about subdepartments. The primary key is the ID Column which is directly related to Nombre Column because It refers to Departments name. The thing is that Each of departments are inside another bigger than 1st one **E.G.:** 
*Petronor is the biggest department, thats why It is not inside another one and the column name of DepartamentoPadreId is null in this field, but Economico Financiera, Fiabilidad y Mantenimiento, Ingeniería y Desarrollo, Producción, P&O, SMA and OTROS are inside of PETRONOR and this is how works this table.*

[image: Departamentos Table]

The problem is that names are too long to put in my Dashboard so what I did was create a new table relating the names from DepartmentoPadreId to another with the acronyms.

[image: Referencia_Direcciones Table]

Now I have my last table where I have the work permits of employees. This permits are made by a Department for another. This means that I have several relations with this table by Departamentos Table. One relation is with the Authorizing Department and another with Authorized Department. **And here is my problem**

[image: PDTs Table]

What I expect to get is two stakked column charts with different values for each one. 
**One:** the Total number of permits by Authorized Department 
**Second:** The total number of permits by Authorizing Department.

[image: The charts I expect to get]

[image: This is what I did]

The problem is I'm getting the name from the Relacion-Direccion Table because is the only table that contains the name I want to appears in my dashboard and I dont know how to filter It by the specific column in PDTs table I want.

Comment: Seems you are using a Line and clustered column chart. Your Line Values is empty, so it is not going to show you  any lines..